# Using AWS Java SDK 2.0 WebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider gives SdkClientException

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I have an application that already works using Kinesis. The application uses AWS Session Credentials but we are switching to using either AWS Session Credentials or Web Identity Token (`software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.WebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider`) depending on the deployment environment.

When I add in the code to use `WebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider` I get the stacktrace below. I can't provide the code but rest assured I'm setting an HTTP client for Kinesis. But if you look at the stacktrace it shows that a default HTTP client is being configured via the Provider deep within the AWS SDK code. I have no influence over the Credentials Provider setting the HTTP client as the `WebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider` doesn't give me a way to tell it that I don't need a default HTTP client being set.

I know one option is to create my own implementation of the `WebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider` but I'd rather not do that.

Question: What else can I do to work around this?

```
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Multiple HTTP implementations were found on the classpath. To avoid non-deterministic loading implementations, please explicitly provide an HTTP client via the client builders, set the software.amazon.awssdk.http.service.impl system property with the FQCN of the HTTP service to use as the default, or remove all but one HTTP implementation from the classpath
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:102)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.loader.ClasspathSdkHttpServiceProvider.loadService(ClasspathSdkHttpServiceProvider.java:62)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1002)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:527)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.loader.SdkHttpServiceProviderChain.loadService(SdkHttpServiceProviderChain.java:44)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.loader.CachingSdkHttpServiceProvider.loadService(CachingSdkHttpServiceProvider.java:46)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.loader.DefaultSdkHttpClientBuilder.buildWithDefaults(DefaultSdkHttpClientBuilder.java:40)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder.lambda$resolveSyncHttpClient$7(SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java:343)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder.resolveSyncHttpClient(SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java:343)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder.finalizeSyncConfiguration(SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java:282)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder.syncClientConfiguration(SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java:178)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.DefaultStsClientBuilder.buildClient(DefaultStsClientBuilder.java:27)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.DefaultStsClientBuilder.buildClient(DefaultStsClientBuilder.java:22)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder.build(SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java:145)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.internal.StsWebIdentityCredentialsProviderFactory$StsWebIdentityCredentialsProvider.<init>(StsWebIdentityCredentialsProviderFactory.java:71)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.internal.StsWebIdentityCredentialsProviderFactory$StsWebIdentityCredentialsProvider.<init>(StsWebIdentityCredentialsProviderFactory.java:55)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.internal.StsWebIdentityCredentialsProviderFactory.create(StsWebIdentityCredentialsProviderFactory.java:47)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.WebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider.<init>(WebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider.java:86)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.WebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider.<init>(WebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider.java:46)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.WebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider$BuilderImpl.build(WebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider.java:200)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that when I was excluding transitive dependencies it wasn't really being excluded.

Below is the dependency I had to exclude in Gradle and had to add an exclusion in every dependency that had this as a transitive dependency. After adding the necessary exclusions, running the gradle dependency report (`./gradlew -q dependencies --configuration runtimeClasspath`), and verifying it didn't show up anymore, then all was good.

```
group: 'software.amazon.awssdk', module: 'url-connection-client'
```